# Custom template not gaining focus nor editable, if you have used mouse click to edit it

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Custom template not gaining focus nor editable, if you have used mouse click to edit it.

Please see [this sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXSSzgkNpYOWOFJHS7q6?p=preview).

Steps to reproduce the issue: 
1) Click a cell under the "Gender" column.
2) Then click any other cell, so that the focus from the custom temlpate is lost and gained by new cell.
3) Click the same cell that you've clicked in STEP #1 above.

After the STEP #3, you will not be able to edit the textfield or use the custom template in the cell. In case this cell is still editable or working for you try the 'Steps to reproduce the issue' a couple of times and you will arrive at this issue.

```
            uiGridEditConstants.events.BEGIN_CELL_EDIT
```

How can I fix this?